# Firefox Plugin, modifying the addressbar behaviour

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, address-bar

I'm looking for a Mozilla reference for how to capture the DOM before resources start to download or to intercept the resources while a page is loading in order to customise how content is cached.

The intended sequence would be something like:

```
Enter a URL into the addressbar and submit it
 > capture the url string and attempt to load any resource found
 > pause default parsing, separately parse & compare to user-defined list
 > run local rules and register functions against resources found in the dom
 > resume default parsing, call registered functions when resources are requested
```

The purpose of this plugin is to allow developers to modify what resources are cached or not cached per page or per site without having to clear their entire cache, so we can investigate how well sites handle failed or delayed resources in a more fine-grained manner.

If you are working on a server and the site is resource heavy, your development can be held up by constant timeouts.  If you need to keep clearing your cache in order to test features, it can make the whole development and testing process over 10x longer than normal.  The aim of the plugin is to give more control over what to cache and when per page and per site so when you clear cache, you can decide exactly what you're clearing and what you're keeping and improve your delivery times in these kinds of conditions.

This is common when working on servers situated in China, Australia, Thailand, etc when you work in the UK/USA and vice versa.

Currently, we're researching where we can hook into Firefox and our devs can't identify where this step might be exposed for a plugin to hook into.

Is there a way to access this step in the existing address bar?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

According to the answers below, it is possible to hook into the browser to pause and resume, but it's not yet clear from the docs if it's possible to get the document before resources in it are called.

Comment: This is a very specific question - what's the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a TabsProgressListener and implement [OnLocationChanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs#onLocationChange) function. This gets called every time user enters a new url in urlbar.

Comment: Hi Kashif, from the documentation, I can't quite tell if this is fired after the page has started downloading or is just triggered so that you can monitor it.  Do you know if it's possible to pass aRequest or aLocation to a function and only let download continue after that function has run?  I'm a bit stuck on whether there's a callback behaviour possible here or just the ability to observe.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that you could ask a request to wait unless you use XPCOM or XBL. For the approach above, you could use nsIRequest.suspend(), call your function and then nsIRequest.resume(). However note that since document is not loaded at this stage, you won't have DOM.

Comment: Hi Kashif, do you see a way where the document could be downloaded, but not start rendering, so that it can be modified before the render begins?  I'm thinking like AdBlockPlus.  This blocks scripts and other resources before they make outbound connections.  I want to achieve something similar but rather than block, I want to redirect those resources to a local file for that resource instead. For that, I'm trying to find where to put the hooks so that a similar kind of overriding behaviour can be applied.